# C++ : how does class variable get modified?

Tags: c++, oop, scope, pass-by-value

From the MSDN page concerning [const functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ke686zh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The code:

```
    // constant_member_function.cpp
class Date
{
public:
   Date( int mn, int dy, int yr );
   int getMonth() const;     // A read-only function
   void setMonth( int mn );   // A write function; can't be const
private:
   int month;
};

int Date::getMonth() const
{
   return month;        // Doesn't modify anything
}
void Date::setMonth( int mn )
{
   month = mn;          // Modifies data member
}
int main()
{
   Date MyDate( 7, 4, 1998 );
   const Date BirthDate( 1, 18, 1953 );
   MyDate.setMonth( 4 );    // Okay
   BirthDate.getMonth();    // Okay
   BirthDate.setMonth( 4 ); // C2662 Error
}
```

But how does `month` get modified in the `setMonth` function? The function is passing by value and returning nothing. Furthermore, how would the function even know about the month variable to modify it without it being passed in?

Comment: `month` gets "modified" in `setMonth` because of the assignment? It even says so in the comment: "Modifies data member"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Furthermore, how would the function even know about the month variable to modify it without it being passed in?

**Member functions** (like `setMonth()`) implicitly receive a `this` pointer to the object of type (in this case) `Date` they are invoked on. For member functions qualified as `const`, the `this` pointer is a pointer to `const`, which won't allow you to modify the state of the pointed object.

In fact, the following:

```
void Date::setMonth( int mn )
{
    month = mn;          // Modifies data member
}
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
void Date::setMonth( int mn )
{
    this->month = mn;          // Modifies data member
//  ^^^^^^
//  "this" is a pointer to an object of type Date (i.e. Date*),
//  and that is the object on which setMonth() is invoked
}
```

Same story for all other member functions, so:

```
int Date::getMonth() const
{
    return month;        // Doesn't modify anything
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
int Date::getMonth() const
//                   ^^^^^ Means the implicit "this" pointer is const
{
    return this->month;        // Doesn't modify anything
//         ^^^^^^
//         Here, "this" is a pointer to a CONST Date object (i.e. Date const*),
//         and that is the object on which getMonth() is invoked
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** The implicit `this` pointer is actually a pointer to `const` if the object on which the member function is invoked has a `const`-qualified type.

This is why you cannot invoke a member function which is not itself `const`-qualified on an object whose type *is* `const`-qualified: *the state of a* `const` *object should never be altered*, and a non-`const` function does not promise to never alter it.

Therefore, the compiler will prevent you from calling a non-`const` function (e.g. `Date::setMonth()`) on an object of a `const`-qualified type (e.g. `const Date`) by raising an error.

Comment: Excellent answer. The implicit nature of the this pointer was confusing me.

Comment: This is a really good clear explanation. Informative and straight to the point. +1

Comment: @Agentlien: Thank you, glad you appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

setMonth is a member method of the Date class, and hence can see all member variables of the Date class

```
void Date::setMonth( int mn )
{
   month = mn;          // Modifies data member
}
```

*mn* is passed in as an argument. In this way whatever you have put as the argument, will be assigned to the month member variable of the class.

Answer (score 1):

`setMonth` is a member function. Therefore, it has an implicit `this` pointer to the object it is operating on. That is, each of the member variables of a particular object are in scope and the (non-const) member functions can modify them.

It may be clearer to rewrite `setMonth`,

```
void Date::setMonth( int mn )
{
   this->month = mn;          // Modifies data member
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that a `const` declared function says that the function will not modify the object on which the function is called. That is, if you do:

```
BirthDate.getMonth();
```

This is OK, because while `BirthDate` is a `const Date`, `getMonth` is declared `const`, and thus guarantees it won't change it.

The reason this doesn't work:

```
BirthDate.setMonth( 4 );
```

is that `setMonth` is not declared `const`, which means it does not leave any guarantee that it will not change `BirthDate`, i.e. the object on which it is called.

It is not the input parameters which get changed, it is the object on which the function is called. In the case of `setMonth`, it is the `month` variable in your `Date` instance which gets modified.

As to how the program knows that the function will modify an object: it doesn't. But you cannot call a function which is not declared `const` on an object which is `const`. Also, trying to modify a (non-`mutable`) member variable in a function declared `const` will give you compiler errors. Hence, the compiler ensures that you do not break your promise. (Though naturally, there are evil standard-conforming ways of sneakily breaking this promise. But that's just immoral and dangerous.)

Answer (score 0):

By defining your object as `const` you are assuring the compiler that the state of the object will not change. It stays in the state like it was created.
When calling your method `setMonth()`, you are changing the state of the object, no matter if you pass by reference or by value.

```
void Date::setMonth( int mn )
{
   month = mn;          // Modifies data member <--- Trying to modify the whole object by changing a part of it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyDate` is an object of the `Date` class.
Each `Date` object has its own `int month` which is known since it is declared. (Even from outside the class you know that `Date` contains an `int month` but you cannot access it, since it is private.
You could also use the `this` pointer (which is a pointer available within each class pointing to ist own memory location).

The code of setMonth is implicitly doing the following:

```
void Date::setMonth( int mn )
{
   (*this).month = mn;          // Modifies data member
}
```